# what does it mean by having 2 equal classes?

Tags: java

```
 public boolean isAfraidOf(Animal animal) {
    //Compare the class of this animal to Bird
    if (animal.getClass() == Bird.class) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

**Animal is the super class and Bird is the subclass , i need to know the differentiator on which they compare the two classes? and thanks in advance**

Comment: It means `animal` is an instance of `Bird`, and not a subclass.

Comment: `return animal.getClass() != Bird.class;` is easier.

Comment: @shmosel thanks for your answer but maybe i couldn't explain it right ,, i gave this part of code as an example .. in my code i have 3 classes  Animal , Bird and cat  Animal is superclass  and the others are subclasses but  i just need to know (in general) when i have to compare 2 classes with each other what's the really thing i compare like if i have 2 numbers so i need to know which of them is smaller .. here i can't understand the idea of comparing 2 classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getClass()` returns the `Class`. So `animal.getClass()` would return type Animal and the comparison would return `false`.

So here is a comprehensive study for your understanding:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();

Bird bird = new Bird();

Animal birdAnimal = new Bird();

if (animal.getClass() == bird.getClass()){
    System.out.println("Bird equals to animal");
}else{
    System.out.println("Bird not equals to animal");
}

if (birdAnimal.getClass() == animal.getClass()){
    System.out.println("BirdAnimal equals to animal");
}else {
    System.out.println("BirdAnimal not equals to animal");
}

if (animal.getClass() == Animal.class){
    System.out.println("animal equals to Animal");
}else{
    System.out.println("animal not equals to Animal");
}

if (animal.getClass() == Bird.class){
    System.out.println("animal equals to Bird");
}else{
    System.out.println("animal not equals to Bird");
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Bird not equals to animal
BirdAnimal not equals to animal
animal equals to Animal
animal not equals to Bird
```

Comment: Note that `animal.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends Animal>`, not `Class<Animal>`. It doesn't *necessarily* return "type Animal" because it could be a subclass.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, but it returns equals. Pasted the original test results.

Comment: @RehAmEL-Gamal My pleasure. If this helps can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to determine if an `Animal` is of the class-type `Bird`. The easiest way to do that is with `instanceof` Example:

```
if (animal instanceof Bird) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

There is another way to do this sort of thing though. In Java, all classes extend `Object` by default. This means that they come with a built in `.equals()` method. However, if you created the Animal and Bird classes, it is very likely the `.equals()` method is insufficient. When you create a new class, you should override the `.equals()` method to compare the object in exactly the way you desire. For example, if all animals have weight, you might want to compare that. Or not. Perhaps you only want to determine equality based on another attribute.

Comment: thanks for your answer .. but regardless this code ,i need to know in general when you compare 2 classes with each other what's the really thing you compare in them ,like if i compare two numbers i'll find one of them is bigger than the other  but i don't know what things i should compare in the two classes?

Comment: @RehAmEL-Gamal Are you asking how the comparison of `Class` objects is done? (e.g. `animal.getClass() == Bird.class`) or how classes are compared in general?

Comment: @RehAmEL-Gamal I edited my post. Tell me if that was what you were looking for.